# datetime manipulation: replace all dates with 00:00 time with 24:00 the previous day

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a table described here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8852/3

The date_time field for when the time is `00:00` is wrong. For example:

```
5/24/2013 00:00
```

This should really be:

```
5/23/2013 24:00
```

So hour `00:00` corresponds to the last hour of the previous day (I didn't create this table but have to work with it). Is there way quick way when I do a select I can replace all dates with `00:00` as the time with `24:00` the `previous day`? I can do it easily in python in a for loop but not quite sure how to structure it in sql. Appreciate the help.

Comment: While `24:00` is valid in *some* places, it is usually not a valid midnight representation in computing.  Some software/platforms make an exception and allow it, but most do not.  [More here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All datetimes are instants in time, not spans of a finite length, and they can exist in only one day.  The instant that represents Midnight is by definition, in the next day, the day in which it is the start of the day, i.e., a day is closed on its beginning and open at its end, or, to phrase it again,  valid allowable time values within a single calendar date vary from 00:00:00.00000, to 23:59:59.9999.

This would be analogous to asking that the minute value within an hour be allowed to vary from 1 to 60, instead of from 0 to 59, and that the value of 60 was the last minute of the previous hour.

What you are talking about is only a display issue.  Even if you could enter a date as 1 Jan 2013 24:00, (24:00:00 is not a legal time of day)  it would be entered as a datetime at the start of the date 2 Jan, not at the end of 1 Jan.
One thing that illustrates this, is to notice that, because of rounding (SQL can only resolve datetimes to within about 300 milleseconds), if you create a datetime that is only a few milleseconds before midnight, it will round up to midnight and move to the next day, as can be seen by running the following in enterprise manager...

```
 Select cast ('1 Jan 2013 23:59:59.999' as datetime)
```

SQL server stoers all datetimes as two integers, one that represents the number days since 1 Jan 1900, and the other the number of ticks (1 tick is 1/300th of a second, about 3.33 ms), since midnight.  If it has been zero time interval since Midnight, it is stll the same day, not the previous day.

If you have been inserting data assuming that midnight 00:00:00 means the end of the day, you need to fix that.

If you need to correct your existing data, you need to add one day to every date in your database that has midnight as it's time component, (i.e., has a zero time component).

```
   Update tbale set 
      date_time = dateAdd(day, 1, date_time)
   Where date_time = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, date_time), 0)
```